# How to include floating Action button to mapActivity java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

i would like to insert floating action button to a map activity so that i can click to view menu here is my floatingButton prepared code :

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="#3490dc"
        app:fab_labelSstyle="@style/custom"
        android:contentDescription="TODO">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fab_title="Camera"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/icon"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:fab_colorNoemal="@color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="#3490dc"
            android:contentDescription="TODO" />
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fab_title="Game"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/icon"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:fab_colorNoemal="@color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="#3490dc"
            android:contentDescription="TODO" />
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fab_title="Video"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/icon"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:fab_colorNoemal="@color/white"
            app:fab_colorPressed="#3490dc"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
  </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>
```

here below my activity_map.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MapActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/whitebutton"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_back" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/toolbar_icon_map"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="Carte"
                android:textColor="#777777" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <!--<TextView
            android:id="@+id/updatetimer"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#777777" />-->

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#e1dfdf" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/zoom_in"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/zoom_in_selector"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/zoom_out"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/zoom_out_selector"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="9dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/showtails"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/tail_active"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/autozoom"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon2022"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/geofences"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/geofence_active"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/map_layer"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/map_layer_change_icon_inactive"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="#3490dc">


        </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i have put only one Floating Button to thr bottom of the card every thing is ok untill i try to run the app it says: `android resources linking failed`
could please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the floating button inside the Coordinator Layout.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Naveen Kumar thank you bro i did it !